# MVC 5 OWIN External Login with Mobile Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, azure-mobile-services

I am doing external login (Facebook, Twitter, Microsoft) using MVC 5 OWIN Identity 2, which works great, but I need to access a mobile services with this credential, I have read that to this I need a access token, so I get the access token and try to pass it to the mobile services, but always has this error:

Facebook: Error:

```
The Facebook Graph API access token authorization request failed with HTTP status code 400
```

Microsoft: Error:

Invalid token format. Expected Envelope.Claims.Signature.

The method that I am trying to use with mobile services is:

```
await mobileservi.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.[ProviderName], token);
```

I read on this link: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296411.aspx

So I am using a `JObject()` to pass the access token

The format of the token that I most pass:

For Microsoft is:

```
token.Add("authenticationToken", _accessToken);
{"authenticationToken":"<authentication_token>"}
```

For Facebook is:

```
token.Add("access_token", _accessToken);
{"access_token":"<access_token>"}
```

But I do not have the format for Twitter.

Now according to Azure Mobile Services documentation, I most use the azure mobile services URL on my apps for any of this providers, but if I do this, I receive an error of incorrect URL when redirecting to the provider log in page.

I read this post with OAuth:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/06/25/exposing-authenticated-data-from-azure-mobile-services-via-an-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx

It has to be something like this for MVC 5 OWIN Identity 2.

On the Startuo.Auth.cs file, I have this configure to get the access token for each provider:

Microsoft:

```
var MicrosoftOption = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "0000000048124A22",
            ClientSecret = "c-gTye48WE2ozcfN-bFMVlL3y3bVY8g0",
            Provider = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationProvider()
            {

                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {

                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(("urn:microsoftaccount:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Microsoft"));

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };
```

Twitter:

```
var twitterOption = new TwitterAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ConsumerKey = "ConsumerKey",
            ConsumerSecret = "ConsumerSecret",
            Provider = new TwitterAuthenticationProvider()
            {

                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {

                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:twitter:accesstoken", context.AccessToken));
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:twitter:accesstokensecret", context.AccessTokenSecret));

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };
```

Facebook:

```
var facebookOption = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "AppId",
            AppSecret = "AppSecret",
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {

                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {

                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };
```

On the externalLoginCallback, this is how a retrieve the access token

```
        string email = null;
        string accessToken = null;

        ClaimsIdentity ext = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        switch (login.LoginProvider)
        {
            case "Facebook":
                accessToken = ext.Claims.First(x => x.Type.Contains("access_token")).Value;
                break;

            case "Twitter":
                accessToken = ext.Claims.First(x => x.Type.Contains("accesstoken")).Value;
                break;

            case "Microsoft":
                accessToken = ext.Claims.First(x => x.Type.Contains("access_token")).Value;
                break;

        }
```

Later I store this value on a session variable, this value is the one that I use to pass as the access token.

So I have no idea what to do, can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found what I was doing wrong, in order to respect the authorization flow, I must have APP ID and APP Secret that I register on my app (Google, Facebook, Microsoft, Twitter), on my mobile service. This is the important part, the register URL in the app must be the URL of the web site, after doing this, everything work fine